# XCTest app tests and permissions alerts

Tags: ios, xctest

I'm writing XCTest app tests that test some `UIViewControllers` by calling `presentViewController` on the `UIApplication` `rootViewController`.

This works fine, except for permissions dialogs.  Some of the `UIViewControllers` make the system pop permissions dialogs for things like camera or microphone access.  I'm not sure how to dismiss them.

If this were a UI test, I could use `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` and `tap` the alert away.

However, I'm not sure how to make this work.  Can an app test access UI test features?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a way to resolve the issue ?

Comment: It appears we need to use Dependency Injection (DI) and/or Mock classes to accomplish this. This [Lynda.com course](https://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Swift-Writing-Testable-Code/590829-2.html), released 5/24/2017 at last view, discusses both. (The course may be available for free as an intro to Lynda.com or through your local library.)

Answer (score 1):

In xcode ui test, to access system pop permissions dialogs, use the below code:

```
self.addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("your alert text", handler: { (alert) -> Bool in
     yourAlertElement.tap()
     return true
     })
```

Hope this will help and if you have any confusion, let me know.

Comment: `addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription` doesn't seem to fire when not in a UI test